# Setting value in pandas mulitindex fails

Tags: python, pandas

I have a mulitindexed dataframe, where i wish to se som values:

```
import pandas as pd
import itertools
a = pd.period_range('2013Q1','2013Q4', freq='Q')
i = (1111, 2222, 3333)
idx = pd.MultiIndex.from_tuples(list(itertools.product(a, i)),
                            names=('Periode', 'CVR'))
df = pd.DataFrame(index=idx,
              columns=('OMS', 'OMK','RES','DRIFT_IND','OEVRIG_IND','FIN_IND','VARE_UD','LOEN_UD','FIN_UD'))
```

Using this to acces a value works:

```
df.loc[('2013Q1',1111),'OMS']
```

However this fails:

```
df.loc[('2013Q1',1111),'OMS']=1
```

with the following errror:

```
 ValueError: can only call with other PeriodIndex-ed objects
```

Does anyone know that the problem is?

Comment: What version of pandas are you using? As accessing the value does not even work on 0.16.0, so that looks like a regression and/or a bug for the assigment.

Comment: I am using '0.14.1'. What would be the correct way to set/acces, as this is the method i found from the documentation / other threads

Comment: @joris this works in `0.16.0` but raises `C:\WinPython-64bit-3.4.3.1\python-3.4.3.amd64\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\index.py:4307: PerformanceWarning: indexing past lexsort depth may impact performance.
  PerformanceWarning)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This works for both accessing and assigning if you use a `Period` object explicitely instead of a string:

```
In [9]: df.loc[(pd.Period('2013Q1'),1111),'OMS']
Out[9]: nan

In [10]: df.loc[(pd.Period('2013Q1'),1111),'OMS'] = 1

In [11]: df.loc[(pd.Period('2013Q1'),1111),'OMS']
Out[11]: 1
```

But I filed an issue for this: https://github.com/pydata/pandas/issues/9892

Comment: Yes, this is a safe way. Although with strings it should also work (it's a bug that it doesn't, eg it works for a DatetimeIndex with strings)